# All ports of Google Compute Engine created from snapshot are closed

Tags: ssh, google-cloud-platform, port, google-compute-engine, firewall

I have a Google Compute Engine instance for which I create a snapshot every day. I now have the need to create an instance from one of the snapshots to recover some files.

So I create the instance from a snapshot but when I try to connect using ssh I get the error:

> port 22: Connection refused.

So I checked the status of the ports and I discovered that **all** of them are closed.

I'm able to connect to the new instance using the serial port and I always connect to the other instance using ssh so the firewall rules should be fine.

Please help, I'm really freaking out.

Answer (score 0):

It still might be a firewall issue, because:

1. serial port is not a subject of firewall rules;
2. when you create instances from a snapshot it doesn't inherit network tags from original instances.

So I would suggest first to check if network tags are the same on your other instances where you can ssh and on instance created from snapshot.

If it doesn't help you definitely should go through [Troubleshooting SSH](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/troubleshooting/troubleshooting-ssh) GCP docs.

Answer (score 0):

I did a quick test on my VM instance; when a firewall rule is causing this issue, telnet gets timed out. Error message ‘Port 22: Connection refused’ indicates SSH service might be stopped. To verify whether the SSH service is running on your affected instance, connect to serial console of the instance [1] and use the following command:

$ sudo netstat -plnt

Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      807/sshd

If you do not see the above service, start the SSH service and try to SSH into the instance:
$ sudo service ssh start

[1] https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/interacting-with-serial-console#connectserialconsole

Comment: "sudo netstat -plnt" doesn't return me the service, but even if I do "sudo service ssh start" the service doesn't seem to start. Now I'm going to google some stuff to understand what's happening to the ssh service. Thank you for pointing me in the right direction!